# Entity Framework Core not compatible DotNet Core class library

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, azure-devops

Admittedly still very new to the DotNet core ecosystem.

I have a solution set-up with several class libraries for a framework I am porting over to DotNet core.

I have them targeting Core 2.1 (netcoreapp2.1).

I have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package installed (v2.2) via NuGet.

Locally everything builds and runs fine.

The build definition (Azure DevOps) is failing because NuGet won't pull the EntityFrameworkCore package.  Specifically:

```
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.2 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
```

The answer seems obvious - but I am confused on this.  DotNet core supports NET Standard 2.0.

Also - I don't get this problem at all locally.

Making it even more confusing - the build actually succeeds if I ignore the NuGet error.

Is there something I need to be doing to make sure the projects explicitly state they are targeting netstandard2.0 in addition to a netcoreapp2.1?

Here is one of the offending project files.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.2" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\ACME.Framework.Common\ACME.Framework.Common.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ACME.Framework.Entity\ACME.Framework.Entity.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Update -

I upgraded to DotNet Core 2.2.  Still getting this problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your purified .csproj?

Comment: posted one of the files.

Comment: Have you run a dotnet restore/NuGet restore? I know it says in the documentation you don't need to but I've had to before. Our Azure DevOps runs the task prior to the build. May I ask why you've not upgraded to .NET Core 2.2? We've got tasks going through at the moment which are fine.

Comment: I have a nuget restore task in the build definition.  That is where the error is occurring.   When it pulls the EF package for one of the projects - I get the compatibility error.   As far as the upgrade - I just got started on this task (porting).  I will try that to see if we get a different result.

Comment: If it's obvious, why not try then to downgrade Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to a lower version?

Comment: @CJohnson - I tried that.  Same error.  I was able to replicate this through the command line.  Visual Studio doesn't surface this error.  I am trying the upgrade to 2.2 right now.

Answer (score 3):

Got it figured out.

My build definition has 3 tasks (NuGet restore, DotNet build, MS Test).

The NuGet restore was failing.  I was able to replicate it by downloading the same CLI version of NuGet that Azure Dev Ops was using (v4.1.0) as of today.

Running NuGet restore - I get the same error.

Changing the task to a dotnet restore eliminates this problem.

I would like to understand what dotnet restore is doing under the hood differently that NuGet is doing.

Comment: Ah that old chestnut. Yeah we've had to alternate between dotnet and nuget tasks. In order to create a NuGet package we had to use dotnet pack and to publish it to our vsix server we had to use the NuGet task.

Comment: The difference between dotnet restore and nuget restore is definitely the subject of another question here on stack overflow.

Comment: glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @Tubs good to know.  I am just getting the deployment pipeline stood-up, so I am glad you told me that I need to switch between the tools ahead of time.  Probably will save me a few hours of headache.

Comment: No problem. It is certainly a fun one but the combination do work. We have internal NuGet and VSIX servers so we had to use all the combinations of the rainbow...